# Sending emails via gmail is too slow

Tags: python, django

I'm using the below to connect to gmail server to send emails.

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myemail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
```

The email is working perfectly fine, but it takes around 20 - 30 secs for the process to complete. I know many are facing this issue, but I didn't find a proper answer for this.

Comment: You often send emails asynchronously, so through a queueing mechanism like rabbit mq.

Comment: Thanks! I haven't used it before! I'll take a look. Can u give me a glimpse about rabbit mq?

Comment: A glimpse: [Documentation: Table of Contents](https://www.rabbitmq.com/documentation.html), [Sending email | Django documentation | Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/email/)

Answer (score -1):

try to add the following line, it works fine for me:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Still it takes the same amount of time to send email